# Minidlna install error (configure: error: Could not find libavformat - part of ffmpeg)

Tags: kodi, software-installation, ffmpeg

I'm pretty new to this Raspberry Pi stuff, and this is the first "project" what I can't get to work.

Raspberry info: Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (Jessie)
The ffmpeg version is: ffmpeg version 2.7.2

```
ffmpeg version 2.7.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree
libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 20.100
libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56.  1.  0
libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56.  1.  0
libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5.  0.  0
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

It's installed at: `/usr/local/bin`

Whenever I'm trying to configure the minidlan-1.1.5 version I'm getting an error:

```
sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libavformat-dev : Depends: libavformat57 (= 10:3.0.2-dmo2) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libavcodec-dev (>= 10:3.0.2-dmo2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Your configure script is looking for some devel files describing how to link to the runtime library. I'm not familiar with ffmpeg, so Ican't help on that front. Make sure that `pkg-config` is installed though.

Comment: Hi @MNoit, thank you for the quick response. I have pkg-config installed.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out! I hope it will help for the someone who is facing the same issue.

Solution:

- open `/etc/apt/sources.conf`:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.conf
  ```
- add the following line:

  ```
  deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
  ```
- save it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>) close it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>).

Now can install libavformat by:

```
sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev
```

If it don't want to work, try to install the dependencies first (and the dependencies' dependencies).

In this way I was able to solve it and now I have a running miniDLNA server.